# jw player controlbar hide and show on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am working with jw player. if the client requirement on mouseover to show control bar otherwise all time hide controlber.. please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set controlbar.idlehide= true and controlbar=over:

controlbar.idlehide ( false )
If controlbar.position is set to over, this option determines whether the controlbar stays hidden when the player is paused or stopped.

Corrected player code (working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/8nHKt/ ):

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='470' height='320' id='single1' name='single1'>
<param name='movie' value='http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf'>
<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
<param name='wmode' value='transparent'>
<param name='flashvars' value='image=http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.jpg&file=http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv&controlbar.idlehide=true&controlbar=over&duration=34&fullscreen=true&stretching=fill'>
<embed
  id='single2'
  name='single2'
  src='http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf'
  width='470'
  height='320'
  bgcolor='#000000'
  allowscriptaccess='always'
  allowfullscreen='true'
  flashvars='image=http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.jpg&file=http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv&controlbar.idlehide=true&controlbar=over&duration=34&fullscreen=true&stretching=fill'
/>
</object>
```

Comment: when player in inisilize the controllber hide and mouse over to controlbar show..

Comment: Please see the corrected player embed code now. 
As i said Please set controlbar.idlehide to true.

Comment: jwplayer doesn't show the controls without you putting your mouse over that video area, so what do you need now?

Comment: @RavinderSingh: Thats right. However JW player shows controlbar when the video is paused or stopped. OP is looking to hide the controlbar even when paused or stopped. Thats what the OP is looking for here, and thats what i have answered!

Comment: @user1051666 : Please Vote Up if the answer is useful to you. It helps more people! -- Peace!

Comment: I Up voted, can you comment / share  doc here, regarding controlbar hiding and show parameters Only